# updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. Flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube-player-flutter

I am using youtube_player_iframe: ^4.0.1 this package for youtube video in my app. I have following error "updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. Flutter" and also not able to play video. After some minutes it shows thumbnail in screen but when I press play button its loading only and not able to play video. Please help me for this I am stuck in this problem.

Followig are my codes:

This are the response from api

```
{
  status: true,
  result: found,
  data: [
    {
      ref_id: 5,
      userid: 106764933065187174744,
      username: TakiRajani,
      link: https: //youtu.be/Sm3pR9FYZcY,
      postDateTime: 30-12-202203: 04PM,
      city: tt,
      channelName: masoomeenchannel
    },
    {
      ref_id: 1,
      userid: taki,
      username: TakiRajani,
      link: https: //youtu.be/wf9oETBOxPY,
      postDateTime: 20-11-2211: 30PM,
      city: Mahuva,
      channelName: adminchannel
    },
    {
      ref_id: 2,
      userid: taki1212,
      username: TakiRajani,
      link: https: //youtu.be/K-MYE2DyS-I,
      postDateTime: 20-11-2212: 52PM,
      city: Bhavnagar,
      channelName: alamdargrpmahuva
    },
    {
      ref_id: 4,
      userid: 1,
      username: Taqi,
      link: testUrl,
      postDateTime: TImeDate,
      city: City,
      channelName: alvichannel
    }
  ],
  totalPosts: 4,
  totalPages: 1,
  perPageLimit: 5,
  currentPage: 1,
  hasNextPage: 0
}
```

Following are my code:

```
Future<LinkModel> getAllLinks() async {
    var url = "https://url.com/MajlisLinks.php";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    print("****" + jsondata.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return LinkModel.fromJson(jsondata);
    } else {
      return LinkModel.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
  }
```

init method

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      params: YoutubePlayerParams(
        showControls: true,
        mute: false,
        showFullscreenButton: true,
        loop: false,
      )
    );
  }
```

ui part:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayerScaffold(
      controller: _controller,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      builder: (context, player) {
        return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Live Program",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 25
                ),),
                centerTitle: true,
                backgroundColor: Color(hexColors('006064')),
              ),
              body: FutureBuilder<LinkModel>(
                future: getAllLinks(),
                builder: (context,snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      var allItem = snapshot.data!.data![index];
                      var videoId = allItem.link!.substring(17);
                      print("///////////////////");
                      print(videoId);
                      return Card(
                        color: Color(hexColors("03A9F4")),
                        elevation: 6,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                           YoutubePlayer(
                             controller: YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(videoId: videoId,
                             autoPlay: false,
                             params: YoutubePlayerParams(showFullscreenButton: true))

                               ),

                          ],
                        ),

                      );
                    }
                    );
                  }else{
                    return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),);
                  }

                },
              ),
            )
        );
      },
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?